# Javascript: How can I click on a button, display something and them click again and return to default?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a small issue: I have some HTML content that is styled with CSS. I created a function in JS and when I click a button, the content gets modified. My wish is to click again on the button and appear the default content (HTML + CSS), some kind of "back to basic". What's the way of doing this without creating classes in CSS and using toggle or without refreshing the page? Just simple: click --> appear changes made in JS, click again --> disappear changes made in JS. Thank you!

```
var switchStatus = false;
$("#switch-button").on("click", function() {
  if(switchStatus === false) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
    $("h1").css("color", "#24242e");
    $(".followers").css("color", "#67627b");
    $(".switch-text").css("color", "#67627b");
    $("#switch-button").css({
      "background-color": "#252b43",
      "color": "lightgrey"
      }).text("Dark Mode");
    $(".my-card").css("background-color", "#f0f3fa");
    $(".card-user").css("color", "#252b43");
    $("h5").css("color", "#252b43");
    $("h2").css("color", "#252b43");
    $(".secondLineCard").css("background-color", "#f0f3fa");
    $(".small-card-actions").css("color", "grey");
    $(".small-card-number").css("color", "#24242e");
    switchStatus = true;
  } else if(switchStatus === true) {
    //What piece of code should I put here to get back to normal content without refreshing the page?
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of changing too much styles with .css() property use .addClass and or .toggleClass Method !   Can you provide markup and CSS too so that I can see what was it before.... basically what you need is toggle !

Comment: Please add HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want to do.

```js
let switchStatus = true;

$("#switch-button").on("click", function () {
  if (switchStatus === false) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
    switchStatus = true;
  } else if (switchStatus === true) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    switchStatus = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<button id="switch-button">switch</button>
</body>
```

The better way to do is use css class with `toggleClass()`

```js
$("#switch-button").on("click", function () {
  $("body").toggleClass("color");
});
```

```css
.color {background-color: coral;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="switch-button">switch</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Yep exactly what I meant !

Comment: Yes, I knew this solution, but I was asking if it is a shorter way to... something like cancel the changes added with JS when clicking the button. But I did with toggleClass and it worked. Thank you, you helped me. It's much clear now. ^_^

Comment: @RobyDobos, no problem. If you think this solution helps you, you can accept this answer to let people know that this question is solved.